# Xamarin processor architecture build error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I updated my VS 2015 recently with the latest patch version and since then I get this error:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Output:

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MoneyFox.Shared, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\nino\Documents\GitHub\MoneyFox.Windows\Src\MoneyFox.Shared\MoneyFox.Shared.csproj(333,3): warning MSB4011: "C:\Users\nino\Documents\GitHub\MoneyFox.Windows\Src\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\portable-net+sl+win+wpa+wp\Fody.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Users\nino\Documents\GitHub\MoneyFox.Windows\Src\MoneyFox.Shared\MoneyFox.Shared.csproj (325,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): error MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only other entry is a warning who should be the reason.
Strange is, that the project who the error occurs doesn't have the mscorlib referenced.

The error occurs in the PCL Shared Library part who is referenced by the platform specific projects. Therefore these can't build aswell.

My current build configuration is as follows:

[image]

The shared project in special:

[image]

Repository: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/AndroidBackgroundService

I tried to repair vs but that didn't change something, as does reinstall it completly.
Funny is, that I can build it on a windows 7 pc (but get runtime error instead).
Also I can't build my master branch anymore who was buildable some days ago.
What's wrong here!?

EDIT: I created a new portable class library and unloaded all other projects.. I get the same error, also when I create a new project with just a portable class library in it. So it seems there is something pretty wrong with my current installation...

Comment: That is a common error and is probably not the issue. I get that quite often and am still able to build and deploy just fine. Which project are you not able to build? I would look in the Output window after the build fails and see what kind of errors show up in there

Comment: I added the logs from the output.. as far as I see there is only a warning.

Comment: Try deleting all `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders from all projects, then do a clean and rebuild.

Comment: I did that several times without success. Also I tried to delete the whole local repo and check it out again. but Without success either.

Comment: What directory values do you have listed for **Java Development Kit Location**, **Android SDK Location**, and **Android NDK Location** when you go to Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings? I recently found another user who had the wrong versions listed there. I would also suggest updating the Xamarin Visual Studio plugin and then opening the Android SDK Manager and make sure all items are up-to-date and installing the latest **Android SDK Build Tools** which is currently 24.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. It seems that some of the .net profile got corrupt. But they didn't get repaired with a reinstall or repair of VS. So, therefore I deleted the Files and folders under the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable

Then I repaired VS and it worked again..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think that this has to do with applying the latest patch to Visual Studio 2015.

We see this warning when we have one project that is built for x86 referencing another build for AnyCPU. This can be fixed in the Project Property page (right-click the project and click Properties). In the Build tap you can set *Platform target*. I would suggest that you set the configuration combo box in the top of the property window to *All configurations* before updating this to get it set consistently.

You can also correct this by unloading the project and editing it manually. Look for the AnyCPU property and insure that it is set in a property group without conditions or in all property groups for each configuration condition.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as far as I know I have all projects on AnyCPU. I added a screenshot of the configuration manger aswell.

Comment: Even though the Configuration Manager says AnyCPU as platform the projects could still have x86 as PlatformTarget, so key is checking the project properties.